# Are double "if" statements allowed in shell scripts

Tags: shell-script

In C language we can use `if(a==b&&a==c)` we can make a double and statement is that possible in unix, to be specific in a shell script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if [ a == b ] && [ a == c ]; then
    // passed conditions
fi
```

Nesting them with bash specific syntax is not so bad:

```
if [[ ( a == b && a == c) || b == c ]]; then
```

But I believe it gets extremely ugly if you want to be `sh` compatible.

Comment: `if [ "$a" = "$b" -a "$a" = "$c" ]; then // passed; fi`
is standard and saves a test

Comment: @DougO'Neal If the variables can contain arbitary data then this is not safe in general. (I can't find a flaw with this specific expression though.) The shell has no way to know which arguments are operators and which arguments are operands: some expressions are ambiguous. For example try to parse `[ -n != -o -n = -o ]`. Ksh93 says yes (I presume because it sees `[ ( -n '!=' ) -o ( '-n' = '-o' ) ]]`), but pdksh, bash, dash and zsh choke.

Comment: @Gilles The double quotes around the variables makes them safe.
`a='-n'; b='!='; c=''; if [ "$a" = "$b" -a "$a" = "$c" ]; then echo passed; else echo failed; fi` parses just fine.

Comment: @DougO'Neal No, the quotes change nothing inside `[ … ]`. This is an ordinary command subject to the ordinary parsing rule, it is not special syntax like `[[ … ]]`.

Comment: @Gilles Then can you show me how you set up the example above using quoted variables so that it doesn't parse in bash?

Comment: @DougO'Neal `bash -c 'n="-n"; o="-o"; e="="; d="!="; [ "$n" "$d" "$o" "$n" "$e" "$o" ]; echo $BASH_VERSION'` → `bash: line 0: [: too many arguments`
`4.2.37(1)-release`

Comment: @Gilles You're right - that breaks.  However, I cannot come up with an example where the test operators are not in variables that doesn't parse.  I also have a hard time justifying putting test operators in variables.

Comment: @DougO'Neal You asked for the test operators in variables so I did it that way! My original comment has them not in variables.

Comment: @Gilles I never asked for the test operators to be put in variables.  You said that my very first example is not safe in general.  I'm still waiting for an example where you can set a, b, and c such that `if [ "$a" = "$b" -a "$a" = "$c" ]; then echo ok; fi` doesn't parse.